# Convert string to variable format

Tags: python

I'm trying to use someone else's code with my own, specifically, I want to grab a variables value from his sheet, but I won't know the variable name right away.

Let's say that he has script A.py with the following:

```
test_1 = "This is the first test"
test_2 = "This is the second test"
```

In my script, which we can call B.py, I have the following:

```
import A

answer = A.test_1
print(answer)
```

And this will print out:

```
This is the first test
```

The problem I have, in this example, is that I don't know whether I want 1 or 2, so instead I want to add it dynamically as needed by creating a new variable once I know which number I want.

```
x = 1
new_var = "test_" + str(x)
```

However, I can no longer call his variable anymore

```
answer = A.new_var
print(answer)
```

This will now result in an AttributError: module 'A' has no attribute 'new_var'

And I will get a syntax error if it try it this way:

```
answer = A."test_" + str(x)
```

Does anyone know how I could get around this?

Comment: You are looking for a dictionary.

Comment: I agree with @Austin, however if it is someone elses code, you could use `exec` but make sure you can't use dictionaries first.

Comment: You could also use [`getattr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr) which purpose is to get the value of a named attribute with a string: `getattr(A, new_var)`

Comment: No, do *not* use `exec`.

Comment: ..... especially if it's someone else's code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
getattr(A, new_var)
```

This is the same as A.test_{x}

Answer (score 1):

Create a dictionary that you can index once you *do* know which you want.

```
tests = {
    'test_1': A.test_1,
    'test_2': A.test_2
}

print(tests["test_1"])
```

Note that this suggests that `A` should be defining the dict itself, rather than a series of numbered variables.